# 403 error when trying to get an image in spring

Tags: java, spring, web-services, http-status-code-403

I have written a simple example REST-API to get and image when there is a request. Following is the java code (I used Spring to build the REST-API)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/image/{itemId}",
        headers = "Accept=image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/gif",
        produces = "image/jpg",
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public BufferedImage getChequeImage(HttpSession session, @PathVariable int itemId, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try{
        InputStream newStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\images\\1409830712475-c9df8fe0-290e-4523-909d-c2f909eb564a.jpg"));
        return ImageIO.read(newStream);
    }catch (IOException e){
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        //return ResponseHandler.sendErrorResponse(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage(), response);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

this returns a **403 forbidden response message**. can someone please help with this.

Comment: Is your RES-API secured through any Authentication/Authorization protocol?

Comment: No there is no such thing. I'm just trying to learn Spring and there is no any Authentication protocol

Comment: as a side note (and you may be fully aware of this), you are decoding a JPEG into a BufferedImage and then getting spring to reencode it again on the response. you could send the jpg binary directly, unless there is a reason to reencode it.

Comment: @SlipperySeal Can you please tell me how to do that also. I don't know hot to do that to

Comment: return a byte[] instead of a BufferedImage. Load the file directly into a byte array:  return IOUtils.toByteArray(newStream) can do that. response type is still image/jpg as per your request mapping. dont forget to close those inputstreams when you are done with them.

Comment: it may sound trivial but does your app has access to `c:\images` directory ?